# jQuery: Plugin Validation, how do I validate a dozen or so different fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using this: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept#extension

I'm trying to alert the user to only upload PNGs, Jpgs, JPEGS and PDFs. On the server end if they do attempt, it will not work. On the user end I want to alert them what they are doing is false. Try a different file type. Maybe even prevent them from submitting the form.

How do I get this to work with 1 dozen file fields?

code:

```
$("#fileForm").validate({
          rules: {
            yourFileFieldNameHere: {
              required: false,
              accept: "png,jpg,jpeg,pdf"
            }
          }
        });
```

I'm assuming the yourFileFieldNameHere is the "name=" of the input field as thats the only parameter that works. I've tried to use the ID name.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Revised the answer, i missed the info about a dozen fields. Try adding a rule for the dozen fields like this:

```
    $("#fileForm").validate({
              rules: {
                //any other rules go here
              }
            });

$('.your-dozen-fields-selector').rules("add", {
 required: false,
 accept: "png,jpg,jpeg,pdf"
});
```

Comment: I need to check two dozen "yourFileFieldNameHere" of different names

Comment: I revised my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Is this " .your-dozen-fields-selector " a class name I specify? It seems to only work on the first one, but not all the rest.